# How can I read in from a csv file by assigning last column as the second value of a tuple?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, pandas, syntax-error

I have a csv file in the with three columns so that, each row is in the format:

> "abcdef"       "uvwxyz"           0

I want to generate a list of tuples, where the first element of the tuple is a dictionary of some features extracted from the first two columns, while the second element is simply the third column (0 or 1 value) values representing the label of the features.

I tried the following but it throws some syntax error saying i is undefined in the last line:

```
dataframe = pd.read_csv(csv_file, header = None, delimiter = "\t")
a = dataframe[0]
b = dataframe[1]
label = dataframe[2]
feature = [(findFeature(x,y), labels) for x,y in i for i, labels in  zip(zip(a,b), label)]
```

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need:

```
feature = [(findFeature(x,y), label) for x,y, label in zip(a,b,label)]
```

Comment: My bad in using zip()!

Answer (score 0):

if you don't need any further transformations you may use `csv` library instead of `pandas`:

```
import csv
with open(csv_file) as f:
    reader  = csv.reader(f)
    feature = [(findFeature(x,y), z) for x,y,z in reader]
```

you can find and example for `csv` package usage [here](https://github.com/dimgold/ETL-with-Python/blob/master/csv_io/CSV-io.ipynb)

Answer (score -1):

I'm guessing you need to transform this `("abcdef", "uvwxyz", 0)` into `("abcdef", 0, "uvwxyz")`:

```
with open(csv_file, "r") as f:
    dataframe = [(a,c,b) for a,b,c in map(lambda x: x.split("\t"), f)]
```

unpacking the tuple `a,b,c` in when splitting each line and repacking to `(a,c,b)`